# Local, persistent data storage in R shiny for multiple users in deployed app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, persistent-storage

I have built a fantasy football-type draft simulator in R shiny. To persistently save the players that have been selected, I have used the global assignment operator `<<-` when saving the table so it is able to be 'seen' in other parts of the app. A short example of how that functions is as below;

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)



TeamData <- data.frame("Pick" = 1:26 , "Team" = paste("Team",1:26) , "Player" = character(26) )
Players <- paste("Player",LETTERS)

ui <-  dashboardPagePlus(collapse_sidebar = TRUE, 
                  
                  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
                  
                  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                                             #####  
                                             sidebarMenu(
                                               menuItem("Tab 1",tabName = "Tab_1"))
                                             #####
                  ), 
                  
                  body = dashboardBody(
                    
                    fluidRow( column(4 , 
                                     selectInput(inputId = "dropdownSelect" , choices = c(paste("Player",LETTERS[1:10])) , label = "Drop down List") , br() , 
                                     actionButton(inputId = "draftButton" , label = "Draft")) , 
                              
                              column(6 , 
                                     dataTableOutput("draftBoard"))
                              
                    )
                    
                  ) 
                  
)
                  
                  

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  
  pick  <- reactiveValues(num = 1)
  
  # To display table upon opening
  output$draftBoard <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    
    datatable(data = TeamData , 
              rownames = FALSE, 
              class = "row-bordered hover stripe nowrap order-column" , 
              options  = list(dom = "t",
                              columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                              paging = F,
                              searching = F,
                              scrollX = F, # 'background-color', '#002651'; 'border-bottom-left-radius','5px'; 
                              info = F))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$draftButton, {
    
    # Using global assignment to save the drafted Player
    TeamData$Player[pick$num] <<- input$dropdownSelect 
    
    # To display table after updating choices
    output$draftBoard <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
      
      datatable(data = TeamData , 
                rownames = FALSE, 
                class = "row-bordered hover stripe nowrap order-column" , 
                options  = list(dom = "t",
                                columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                paging = F,
                                searching = F,
                                scrollX = F, 
                                info = F))
      
    })
    
    # +1 to count
    pick$num <- pick$num + 1
    
    updateSelectInput(session , inputId = "dropdownSelect" , choices = setdiff(Players, TeamData$Player))
    
    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

After deploying the app using shinyapps.io and sharing the link for others to use, I discovered (the hard way) that global assignment in this way does not let the app work as intended, as when multiple people are on using the app, other peoples draft selections are showing up in their session, along with a host of other issues.

After reading about persistent data storage in R, im still unsure how to code the app so it is able to:

a) be 'seen' by other parts of the app; that is the equivalent of the TeamData df with the draftees can be saved & accessed in other areas of the app.

b) so that when shared with multiple people each has their own localised session of the app without overriding each others work.

Any help or material to seek out on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `reactive` or `reactiveValue` to store your table. It will be accessible throughout your app, but not accessible to other simultaneous users. Below is a minimal example.

Its an easy error to make. shinyapps.io will often have a single R instance serve multiple users. This means that anything stored globally, i.e. using `<<-`, will impact / be visible to all users in that instance.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectInput(inputId = "drp_players", choices = paste("Player", LETTERS), label = "dropdown"), 
    
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_draft" , label = "Draft"), 
    
    tableOutput("table")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    #Reactive Value to Store Dataframe
    reactives <- reactiveValues(
        
        df_draftboard = data.frame(
            pick             = seq(1:26),
            team             = paste("Team", 1:26),
            player           = "",
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
        
    )
    
    #Table Output
    output$table <- renderTable({
        
        reactives$df_draftboard
        
    })
    
    #Draft Button is Pressed
    observeEvent(input$btn_draft, {
        
        #Work out which pick number we are up to
        picknumber <- sum(reactives$df_draftboard$player != "") + 1
        
        #Add picked player to draft board
        reactives$df_draftboard$player[picknumber] <- input$drp_players
        
        #Update dropdown
        updateSelectInput(session, "drp_players", choices = setdiff(paste("Player", LETTERS), reactives$df_draftboard$player), label = "dropdown")
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, this solution works well - I learned something today. Cheers.